# working on local sever but not live

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `min_price` >= '500000 ' AND `max_price` <= ' 50000000' AND `deleted` =0 AND `blocked` =0 ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

This is working fine on local server but on live sever.
Anywhere brackets requir[image] ?

Comment: What means *but on live sever* any error message?

Comment: change `max_price` <= ' 50000000'  to `max_price` <= '50000000' remove space before the value

Comment: not getting any record

Comment: have you _got_ any records which match the criteria? The most obvious difference between two DBs with the same schema which return different records in response to the same query is the potential for the data contained in them to be different. Unless it's not, in fact, the same query.

Comment: thank you its working @chirag

Answer (score 2):

There is an extra space in to the comparison value.Remove that extra space and it will be work.

```
SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `min_price` >= '500000' 
AND `max_price` <= '50000000' AND `deleted` =0 AND `blocked` =0 ORDER BY `id` DESC
```